# Why semaphore?

Tags: operating-system, ipc, semaphore

Why use binary semaphores when the same functionality can be achieved with a simple variable ?

Answer (score 6):

Because a semaphore isn't a simple variable, it's a larger construct than that.

Specifically, with a counting semaphore (which a binary semaphore is, effectively, with a count of 1), there's the added capability of blocking any process/thread that tries to increment the semaphore above its maximum value.

Semaphores also have the additional facility that their state is changed "atomically", which means that the underlying memory is surrounded by logic to ensure that the CPU caches and such are flushed, and that when the value is changed, it's changed for "everyone". This is particularly important on modern multi-core processors.

The semaphore is appropriate to use when you are trying to guard a shared resource from over use. A binary semaphore is perfect for resources that can only be used by one process/thread at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Because a variable does not work across processes. A system semaphore does.

Answer (score 3):

A number of reasons. Because a semaphore is provided by the operating system, it can...

a) be shared among multiple processes.

b) be used to block processes in waiting, instead of busily waiting.

c) actually work. A variable shared by multiple threads, or in shared memory space for multiple processes, won't give you the safety of a semaphore, because you never know when your thread/process will lose control. When you acquire a binary semaphore, you KNOW you are the only thread/process in that code section, the OS guarantees that.

I recommend you read a book on this, it's kinda a silly question :) no offence!

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores atomic operations are essential to multi-threaded code, otherwise there would be no way to determine which thread went first. For example if you have two threads that process email requests and you want each person to only get one email; you need to determine if an email request has already been processed. Without a semaphore here is what happens:

```
Thread A checks if email[0] has been read, it has not
Thread B checks if email[0] has been read, it has not
Thread A sends email[0] and marks it as done
Thread B sends email[0] and marks it as done
```

For the user the email has been sent twice because both threads saw it as not processed. Now with a semaphore here is what happens to the email:

```
Thread A marks email[0] as in progress via a semaphore
Thread B checks email[0] and sees the semaphore is marked
Thread A sends email[0] and marks it as done then unmarks the semaphore
```

With the semaphore only one thread will process the email.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Semaphore is not like a single variable. As explained above it comes with so many advantages. You can read the book, "The Little Book of Semaphores, 2nd Edition,By Allen B. Downey" for more details about semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

A semaphore restricts access across processes, while a variable, even one that is global to your application, cannot do the same system-wide.

Besides, why reinvent the wheel? You'd have to handle all of the implementation yourself with a variable, whereas with a semaphore, the functionality is already provided by the operating system and guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume a simple way of implementing a resource protection could be done by using a variable i.e. a BOOLEAN. I'll give an example:

```
while {resource_protected == TRUE}
{
// resource is protected
}
```

Now we can protect a resource by setting `resource_protected == TRUE`.

To check if the resource is available we just use something like this:

```
if {resource_protected == FALSE}
{    // <---- rescheduling possible here!
resource_protected == TRUE; // protect resource
}
else
{
//try again later
}
```

But there are two problems with this method. First, this creates a *busy wait* thus the processor is not free to do other stuff. Second, and more important, this active process can be rescheduled (moved to waiting queue) *after* it checks the BOOLEAN but *before* it protects the resource by setting the BOOLEAN to TRUE thus creating the illusion for other processes that the resource is still free, because the BOOLEAN is not yet set. This allows an other process to claim the resource. A now active process (promoted from waiting queue to running due to rescheduling) protects the resource by setting the BOOLEAN to TRUE (because it has not been set by the rescheduled process in the waiting queue). Now this active process is rescheduled and the previous process becomes active again it will set the BOOLEAN to TRUE (although it has been set to TRUE already by the second process) because it has already checked the BOOLEAN. Now both processes claim the *same* resource and you will die an old man trying to debug this mess.

With semaphores you can avoid this ugly ugly mess because it allows atoms. Atoms are sets of instructions which appear *indivisible* from the perspective of other processes. Thus avoiding such mishaps through bad rescheduling.